# Como obtener los datos de este archivo con PHP

Tags: php

Como puedo sacar la informacion de la línea `play_addr` y la calidad `"ratio":"720p"` ya que soy algo novato usando funciones en PHP solo quiero un ejemplo para aprender

es un archivo `JSON` donde esta la informacion

```
var data = {
    "risk_infos": {
        "warn":false,"content":"","risk_sink":false,"type":0}

    ,"label_top": {
        "url_list":["http:\/\/p16-tiktokcdn-com.akamaized.net\/obj\/tiktok-obj\/1598708589477025.PNG","https:\/\/p16-tiktokcdn-com.akamaized.net\/obj\/tiktok-obj\/1598708589477025.PNG","http:\/\/p16-tiktokcdn-com.akamaized.net\/obj\/tiktok-obj\/1598708589477025.PNG","https:\/\/p16-tiktokcdn-com.akamaized.net\/obj\/tiktok-obj\/1598708589477025.PNG","http:\/\/p16-tiktokcdn-com.akamaized.net\/obj\/tiktok-obj\/1598708589477025.PNG","https:\/\/p16-tiktokcdn-com.akamaized.net\/obj\/tiktok-obj\/1598708589477025.PNG"],"uri":"tiktok-obj\/1598708589477025.PNG"}

    ,"author_user_id":188158835147382784,"item_comment_settings":0,"rate":10,"create_time":1522878942,"video": {
        "ratio":"720p","origin_cover": {
            "url_list":["\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/a8f4505c-a16f-44a1-8d3f-27a24be38091_KHUspvwjWI.jpg"],"uri":"http:\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/a8f4505c-a16f-44a1-8d3f-27a24be38091_KHUspvwjWI.jpg","preview_url":"\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/img\/http:\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/a8f4505c-a16f-44a1-8d3f-27a24be38091_KHUspvwjWI.jpg~tplv-tiktok-play.jpg"}

        ,"play_addr": {
            "url_list":["\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/6540715167737451535_XOmKXwzFpY.mp4"],"uri":"6540715167737451535"}

        ,"cover": {
            "url_list":["\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/a8f4505c-a16f-44a1-8d3f-27a24be38091_KHUspvwjWI.jpg"],"uri":"http:\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/a8f4505c-a16f-44a1-8d3f-27a24be38091_KHUspvwjWI.jpg","preview_url":"\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/img\/http:\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/a8f4505c-a16f-44a1-8d3f-27a24be38091_KHUspvwjWI.jpg~tplv-tiktok-play.jpg"}

        ,"height":960,"width":540,"download_addr": {
            "url_list":["\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/6540715167737451535_XOmKXwzFpY.mp4"],"uri":"6540715167737451535"}

        ,"has_watermark":true,"play_addr_h264": {
            "url_list":["http:\/\/v16.muscdn.com\/9d1dbe754d53a1a4b527694470c971d3\/5c610565\/video\/tos\/maliva\/tos-maliva-v-0068\/c4aeed8f3bbd4226b859974afa8b9ee2\/?rc=OGkzOTNpOzU5ZDRlNTlmNkApQHRwbndsQG85Rjg8MzczNDQ4OjozNTwzQCl1KUBnM3cpQGZlemV6b2Z2cGY2NUAvMV4xMzUvXjUxMi8tL2JhczVvI1xsaHFvIzQyMy8xLS4tLS8uLi4tLi9pOmItbyM6YC1vI2IrYiteZnI6IzAuXg%3D%3D","https:\/\/api2.musical.ly\/aweme\/v1\/play\/?video_id=d3ec26022b514a86a2288f6046a04f25\u0026line=0\u0026ratio=720p\u0026media_type=4\u0026vr_type=0\u0026test_cdn=None\u0026improve_bitrate=0"],"url_key":"d3ec26022b514a86a2288f6046a04f25_h264_720p","uri":"d3ec26022b514a86a2288f6046a04f25"}

        ,"duration":14000,"is_h265":0,"play_addr_lowbr": {
            "url_list":["\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/6540715167737451535_XOmKXwzFpY.mp4"],"uri":"6540715167737451535"}

        ,"dynamic_cover": {
            "url_list":["http:\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/35ae581c-cfb6-490c-b123-f1a611203dd4_jjsLnThzKc.webp"],"uri":"http:\/\/mpak-suse1.akamaized.net\/reg02\/2018\/04\/05\/05\/35ae581c-cfb6-490c-b123-f1a611203dd4_jjsLnThzKc.webp"}
    }
}
```

Este es el codígo que estoy usando:

```
function url_get_contents($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$PHP_cUrl  = url_get_contents('https://m.tiktok.com/v/6540715167737451535.html');
$Document = new DOMDocument();
$Document->loadHTML($PHP_cUrl);
$ScriptNodes = $Document->getElementsByTagName('script');
foreach($ScriptNodes as $Script){
   if( strpos($Script->nodeValue, 'play_addr') && strpos($Script->nodeValue, 'ratio') ){
   $cadena = $Script->nodeValue;
   $cadena = substr($cadena, strpos($cadena, "=") + 1 );
   $json = json_decode($cadena);
    echo $json->video->play_addr->url_list[0];
    echo $json->video->ratio;
   }
}
```

Comment: Pero, ¿qué es `var data` en tu PHP?. ¿Esa sintaxis es PHP? ¿Eso es un JSON? ¿Tienes eso así tal cual en tu código?

Comment: Por lo que entendí, tienes un archivo HTML y dentro un <script> que tiene ese JS y quieres tomarlo con el PHP y acceder a esos datos mediante PHP. Por que no pruebas con un Ajax que envié esos datos al PHP y con un `json_decode()` lo tomas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

soy de los que prefiere la manera antigua pero esto te puede servir:

```
<?php

function url_get_contents($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$PHP_cUrl  = url_get_contents('https://m.tiktok.com/v/6540715167737451535.html');

// con expresion regulares buscamos en el string "var data = " y obtenemos todo lo que este luego de ello hasta el ";"
preg_match_all("/var data =(.*?);/", $PHP_cUrl,$matches);
//obtenemos pa poscion 1, ya que la posicion 0 es la coincidencia del patron completo y la 1 contendra solo la concidencia entre parentesis 
$json = json_decode($matches[1][0],true);
$ratio = $json["video"]["ratio"];
$url = $json["video"]["play_addr"]["url_list"][0];

echo "con regex: <br>ratio: {$ratio} <br>url: {$url}";
echo "<hr>";

// creamos un arreglo utilizando la linea "var data = " como separador y obteniendo el elemento siguiente 1
$tmp_data = explode("var data = ",$PHP_cUrl)[1];
// creamos otro arreglo utilizando a linea "$(function(){" como separador que es el final del json y obtenemos los anterior 0
$tmp_data = explode("$(function(){",$tmp_data)[0];
// hacemos un trim para eliminar los espacios antes y despues; luego un rtrim para eliminar el ";" del final y convertimos a json
$json = json_decode(rtrim(trim($tmp_data),';'),true);

$ratio = $json["video"]["ratio"];
$url = $json["video"]["play_addr"]["url_list"][0];

echo "con explode:<br>ratio: {$ratio} <br> url: {$url}<br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, estás afirmando que necesitas obtener dichos valores en PHP cuando la sintaxis es de JavaScript. Afirmando que esa cadena la tienes almacenada en una variable en PHP, lo primero seria obtener la cadena para trabajarla.

**EDITADO**

Para empezar a trabajar con la cadena, hay que obtenerla del archivo. Por lo que [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) nos ayudará.

```
$Document = new DOMDocument();
$Document->loadHTMLFile("Ruta al fichero HTML");
```

Con ésto, podemos empezar a manipular los elementos dentro de PHP como si estuvieramos en JavaScript. Ahora lo que hay que hacer es elegir entre todas las etiquetas  la que contiene la cadena que buscamos.

```
$ScriptNodes = $Document->getElementsByTagName('script');
foreach($ScriptNodes as $Script)
   if( strpos($Script->nodeValue, 'play_addr') && strpos($Script->nodeValue, 'ratio') ) $cadena = $Script->nodeValue;
```

Como referencia buscamos las cadenas de texto "play_addr" y "ratio" a la vez para evitar coincidencias no deseadas.

Ahora hay que lidiar con el inicio de la cadena (var data =) para poder convertir el resto a un objeto en PHP.

```
$cadena = substr($cadena, strpos($cadena, "=") + 1 );
```

Busca la posicion del primer signo de igual (=) y le suma uno para poder eliminar el fragmento de la cadena innecesaria.

```
$json = json_decode($cadena);
```

Una vez hecho esto, puedes ingresar facilmente a los datos que necesitas mediante:

```
$json->video->play_addr->url_list[0];
$json->video->ratio;
```

Y esto te devolveria los valores respectivos que necesitas.

Comment: bueno en verdad es un archivo html y dentro tiene la etiqueta <script> donde estan esos datos que quiero obtener pero no se como

Comment: Lo he editado, con lo que me dices me das una explicacion mas clara.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que tienes un archivo HTML externo y no tienes control sobre el, estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: algo estoy haciendo mal porque me funcion el code, ariba pune el codígo que estoy usando

Comment: Intenta usar $HTML=file_get_contents('URL'); y cargas $Document=$DOMDocument->loadHTML($HTML);